# Different scripts for Desktop and Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on this [website](http://starhill.spinpagency.com/), and I have a script that works quite well on desktop, but I would like to make some modifications on mobile.

The script I have provided below will generate the 'menu box items' as the user is scrolling down.
Then, as the user keeps scrolling down, the boxes will a get zero opacity.

Now, this script is not working that good on mobile (especially on iOS). So what I would like to do is:
Instead of having an opacity of 0 at the beggining, I would like the boxes to have an opacity of 1 when the page is loaded.
Then, as the user makes his/her first scroll on mobile, the boxes will get an opacity of 0.

The code can be tested [here](http://starhill.spinpagency.com/).

```js
$(document).scroll(function () {
    $('.hContentV2>div').each(function () {
        var dataOpacity = $(this).attr('data-opacity');
        var opacityValue = $(document).scrollTop() / 500;
        var aosDelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (700 - 100 + 1)) + 100;
        var t = $('.hotelSection2').offset().top;
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150 && $(document).scrollTop() < ($('.hotelSection2').offset().top - 300)) {
            if (opacityValue >= dataOpacity) {
                opacityValue = dataOpacity;
            }
            $(this).css({ 'opacity': 1, 'transition-delay': aosDelay + 'ms' });

        }
        else if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 100) {
            var opacityValue = 0;
            $(this).css('opacity', opacityValue);
        }
        else if ($(document).scrollTop() > $('.hotelSection2').offset().top) {
            var opacityValue = 0;
            $(this).css('opacity', opacityValue);
        }
    });

    if ($(document).scrollTop() < 100) {
        $('.scrollTopButton').css({ 'opacity': 1 });
    }
    else {
        $('.scrollTopButton').css({ 'opacity': 0 });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the width of the device

E.g

```
if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 900){
            //script
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First detect the device mobile device with this script

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    // YOur less opacity code will be here for ios
}
else{
   //Your normal code here    
}
```

or you can do same by detecting the width of screen to detect the mobile screens

```
if(window.screen.width < 768){

   // Your ios code here for mobile
}
else{

}
```

Like this.

I hope it helped you.

Comment: This helps but I need the script modifications for mobile

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are trying to say. The above code is for modification only